# In linux, to implement something in the kernel, why do we also need to change the user space head file?

Tags: linux, kernel, space

I am trying to implement some kind of new Linux task scheduler so I found this article http://www.eetimes.com/design/embedded/4204929/Real-Time-Linux-Scheduling-Part-1 
is really helpful. However, it said that  we not only need to define the new scheduling macro in /kernel-source-code/include/linux/sched.h  but also need to define the same thing in /usr/include/bits/sched.h.

So why do we need to change the user space head file since the scheduler works in the kernel. I do not know why do we have the user space head file? Anyway the user space program can not use the function defined in the kernel directly (unless through a system call), right? And if we also need to change the user space file in order to implement a new scheduler, then how can the scheduler be portable since the user not only needs to use the new kernel image but also needs to change their user space file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article talks about adding a new *class* of scheduling, or new *scheduling policy*, and not about replacing kernel scheduling algorithm wholesale. You need userland process be able to select the policy with [`sched_setscheduler(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html), thus the need for userland-visible header file.

Take a look [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi,thx.What you said makes sense. So if we  do not define it in the user space , then for example calling sched_setscheduler(NEW_POLICY) in the user space will give error since the user space do not know what is NEW_POLICY, right? So in order to deploy such new scheduler, the developer not only need to provide the user with the new kernel source code but also need to give some instructions to teach the user to add something in the user space file ,right?

Comment: I mean the user space also needs to be patched.